# onchange event not working on calendar control

Tags: javascript, html

i have a textbox named date and a link as shown below

```
<input type="text" name="date">
<a href="javascript:" onclick="cal.select(document.getElementById('date')"><img src='cal.jpg'>
```

once i click on the calendar icon, calendar appears . if i select date it gets populaged in textbox named "date". now i need to write an ajax code to populate another drop down BASED ON the date selection. And hence i tried onchange event on date textbox.

```
<input type="text" name="date" onChange="javascript:getDate()">
```

javascript.js is the file where i have all my js. but i wonder the change event is not getting called once the value changes. But the value is getting populated correctly based on the user date selection.

Question : How to make an onchange event on this .

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a bit of an old question, but is it imperative that the user click on the calendar image? You might be able to make an easy fix this way:

```
<input type="text" name="date" onFocus='javascript:cal.select(document.getElementByID("date");' onBlur="javascript:getDate()">
```

That way, when you click the calendar, it will blur the field and immediately call the javascript function.